# Ng model with no parameters in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angular-ngmodel

I have a filter that when i'm passing in the controller it comes undifined.

This is my template.

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-show="filtroReduzido" class="col-md-2">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Codigo Reduzido</label>
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input no-hint right" style="padding-top: 3px;">
      <select id="reduzido" name="reduzido" chosen width="150" allow-single-deselect="true" ng-model="vm.filtro.numero_contrato" style="width:100%"
        ng-options="clienteFiltro as cliente.Numero_Contrato for cliente in vm.importacaoSiltDet |unique:'Numero_Contrato'| orderBy:'Numero_Contrato'"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

IN the controller i'm using.

```
vm.filtro = {};
```

and in the function i'm using this but in test if comes undifined, i think it was supose to work in the vm.filtro.numero_contrato, someone knows what is causing this?

```
vm.filtrarDetFiltrado = function () {
            debugger;
            var dateDe = formatarData(vm.relatorio.dataDe);
            var dateAte = formatarData(vm.relatorio.dataAte);
            var test = vm.filtro.numero_contrato;
```

Comment: add your filter code.

Comment: My filter? Its the first code part,the template.It comes with values,it's not empty but in my controller is undifinied